Open a Windows app on specific monitor from a shortcut or command line
I need to open an app on specific monitor immediately, either from from a shortcut or command line, and eventually, via a hotkey. A free third-party utility would be good.
Moving a window manually with Windows+arrow hotkeys is not an acceptable option, and I cannot rely on saved window locations because they reset when a monitor is disconnected.
There's a supposed built-in solution for Windows 11 that isn't confirmed to work, while I need a solution for 10 or higher.
The question isn't limited to this kind of use, but for instance, the last time this was needed is when there was a hanging, always-on-top window on monitor 1, and I couldn't move task manager or CLI to monitor 2 to kill a process because they immediately lost focus. Having an alternative to Ctrl+Shift+Esc but only for monitor 2 would help this.
Duplicate questions do not contain such restrictions and so, suitable answers.

Not sure if this will help, however I wonder if vdesk or SysInternals Desktops could be used to create a new virtual desktop directly on a second monitor. vdesk can create a new virtual desktop and can open programs on a specific virtual desktop. On the other hand, Desktops creates an entirely separate Windows Shell as a virtual desktop (only one of these can be used, since Desktops replaces the native virtual desktop feature when used)

@JW0914 I doubt it does exactly this, but I actually used a virtual desktop for my example to get rid of impenetrable window and kill a process, but this requires virtual desktops to be enabled

Virtual Desktops are enabled by default on Windows ≥10, however for Desktops, it would have to be enabled; once it is, I believe it stays enabled, otherwise a startup item may need to be added. You may want to give Desktops a try, as my hunch is it would at least prevent a program on the default Windows Shell from stealing focus from other Windows Shells since all virtual desktops are their own individual Windows Shells, each having their own explorer.exe instances. The way I'm envisioning this is monitor 2 being assigned its own virtual desktop with Desktops (this may not be what you want)
